# SwiftUI EditButton() does not work when set editMode in NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have `EditNoteHost` view which displays `NoteView` or `EditNote` depending on editMode environment variable. Aslo `Cancel` button is displayed in edit mode:

```
struct EditNoteHost: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    
    @State private var draftNote = Note.default
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            
            HStack {
                if editMode?.wrappedValue == .active {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        draftNote = modelData.selectedNote
                        editMode?.animation().wrappedValue = .inactive
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                EditButton()
            }
            
            if editMode?.wrappedValue == .inactive {
                NoteView(note: modelData.selectedNote)
            } else {
                EditNote(note: $draftNote)
                    .onAppear {
                        draftNote = modelData.selectedNote
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        modelData.selectedNote = draftNote
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct EditNoteHost_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EditNoteHost()
            .environmentObject(ModelData())
    }
}
```

This code works fine.

Now I want to use `EditNoteHost` in `NavigationLink` and start it in edit mode:

```
NavigationLink(destination: EditNoteHost().environment(\.editMode, Binding.constant(EditMode.active)).environmentObject(modelData)) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
```

This part of code opens `EditNoteHost` in edit mode if click `+`. However, Done and Cancel buttons do nothing when tap.

How can I fix this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDWKa.png)

Comment: Please provide standalone minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `editMode` using `.constant(EditMode.active)`, it will remain active. So do not set the environment for `editMode`; instead use:

```
NavigationLink(destination: EditNoteHost()) {
    Image(systemName: "plus")
}
```

and in `EditNoteHost`, use:

```
.onAppear() {
    editMode?.animation().wrappedValue = .active
}
```

Comment: EditNoteHost().environment(\.editMode, Binding.constant(EditMode.active) means that editMode environment variable will have active state. This is exactly what I need.EditButton() should change state of environment variable but nothing happens

Comment: yes .constants means that it's always gonna be .active try to avoid using .constant. I edited my answer, let me know if it solves your problem!

Comment: @ S_dnomseD thank you for answer. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. This will work fine when I create notes. In this case I need edit mode. However, when I select existing notes I need to use EditNoteHost in inactive mode(

Comment: In that case you can pass a boolean value to EditNoteHost, and in onAppear use: if editing { editMode?.animation().wrappedValue = .active }else { editMode?.animation().wrappedValue = .inactive }. So when you need it active pass EditNoteHost(editing: true), inactive EditNoteHost(editing: false).

Comment: S_dnomseD this looks like a solution. Thank you!