# SwiftUI IOS: Editable list in a form?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-form

I would like to make my list in a form editable and sortable with the editMode. I've already tried using .environment(.editMode, .constant(.active)) on the list or on the ForEach loop, but unfortunately that didn't work. I'm happy about help.

**What I want:**

https://youtube.com/shorts/vSE6g-NVuE4?feature=share

**Current code:**

```
                        Form {
                            ForEach(elements, id: \.id) { element in
                                Text(element.name)
                            }
                            .onMove(perform: { _, _ in
                                
                            })
                            .onDelete(perform: { _ in
                                
                            })
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden, edges: .bottom)
                            .environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
                        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63518487/12299030?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI EditButton() does not work when set editMode in NavigationLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936588/swiftui-editbutton-does-not-work-when-set-editmode-in-navigationlink)